# Which music video involves a plane crash?

Tags: identify-this-song, music-video

Which song / music video involves a plane crash? The video starts with the singer singing in his airplane seat. Outside the plane is stop motion or some other form of animation with cotton ball clouds. The plane disintegrates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GHyLhbdzN0) is by [Bright Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bright_Eyes_(band)) and the song is the first track "At the Bottom of Everything" from the album [I’m Wide Awake, It’s Morning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_Wide_Awake,_It%27s_Morning).